# elasticsearch and groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, scripting, elasticsearch

I'm playing around with groovy scripting.

By checking groovy lang plugin source code I found next steps in code execution:

1. Code compilation into script class
2. Script initialization via static method newInstance()
3. Script execution via calling the code on each document with binding document parameters

Now assume I have class declaration in my script. Is it possible to execute class definition and class object initialization only once, and execute only a method from this object on each document?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think having a method and calling from script is possible, I am not sure about that. I've tested it had thrown exception.

Comment: it's not possible to write something like `if (!Class.forName('A')) { Class A {} }` because I can't declare a class in `if` block

Comment: you can try with custom plugin... Hope you can perform these things over there..